# ReactPlayer can not play video when given a locahost url address

Tags: reactjs, react-player

`ReactPlayer.js` cannot play the video streamed from an API.

```js
<video controls src='http://localhost:3001/api/video/my_video' /> // it works

<ReactPlayer url="http://localhost:3001/api/video/my_video"  controls/> // failed to work
```

What is displayed using a `<video>` HTML element:

[image]

What is displayed when I use `ReactPlayer`:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work if you're facing CORS cross-origin restriction issue

```
<ReactPlayer
  url="http://localhost:3001/api/video/my_video"
  config={{
    file: {
      attributes: {
        crossOrigin: "true",
      }
    }
  }}
  controls
/>;
```

Comment: But its not stable, it works on  and off

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to config CORS on the server side.

```js
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors()); // installing cors middleware so that any request can be accepted to get the resource i.e video streams.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you explain how you configured CORS?